異なるカラースペースでも共通の色数値は、ないのですか？
現状理解
・カラースペース(RGB、CMYK、Labなど)ごとに色を数値化可能。
・モニター閲覧系はRGB、印刷系はCMYK。
・色数値は、異なるカラースペース間でも変換できる。
Q1.異なるカラースペース間での色数値変換は、可逆変換ではなく近似値変換ですか？
異なるカラースペース間での色数値変換を何回も繰り返すと、色はずれていきますか？
Q2.(光の具合とかインクによっても色は違って見えると思うので、そういう人間の見た目を抜きにして、)異なるカラースペースでも共通の色数値(可逆変換できるような数値)は、ないのですか？
カラースペース毎に再現できない色がありますか？

異なるカラースペース間での色数値変換について、すべての色を可逆変換できない、ということは分かりました。
一点疑問があるのですが、可逆変換できる色もありますか？
ここで言う可逆変換とは、「Aカラースペース」から「Bカラースペース」へ色変換後、「Bカラースペース」から「Aカラースペース」へ再度色変換して、「Aカラースペース」の色を「Aカラースペース」にて完全再現できる、という意味です。
「Aカラースペース」と「Bカラースペース」の見た目上の色が異なっていても、構いません。

今回の質問は re9 さん自身が 直面している実際の問題に基づいたもの でしょうか？「変換後に元のカラースペースにもう一度変換」というのをやろうとしていますか？ / カラースペース A, B と曖昧な表現ではなく、具体的な名前を埋めたほうがよいQAになりそうです。


異なるカラースペースでも共通の色数値は、ないのですか？

定義の上では CIE XYZ色空間 を用いると「標準的な観察者(人間)が知覚できる全ての色情報」を値として表現できます。これ以外の全てのカラースペースは、数式としてはXYZ色空間との間で相互可逆変換を行えます。


Q1.異なるカラースペース間での色数値変換は、可逆変換ではなく近似値変換ですか？
異なるカラースペース間での色数値変換を何回も繰り返すと、色はずれていきますか？

数式の上では可逆ですが、現実問題としては近似変換と考えたほうが良いです。

あるカラースペース上の値は、コンピュータシステムで取り扱える整数値もしくは浮動小数点数に近似表現されます。
あるカラースペース上における値の定義域（例：0.0～1.0 や 0～255）が存在するため、値のクリップ（飽和）処理により非可逆となるケースがあります。


Q2.(光の具合とかインクによっても色は違って見えると思うので、そういう人間の見た目を抜きにして、)異なるカラースペースでも共通の色数値(可逆変換できるような数値)は、ないのですか？

印刷物カラーマネージメントで用いるCMYK色空間は4次元の情報量をもつため、XYZ色空間などの3次元値からは原理的に1:多対応となります。同一XYZ値に対応するCMYK値が複数存在するため、例えば CMYK → XYZ → CMYK は同一値に戻らない可能性があります。

カラースペース毎に再現できない色がありますか？

XYZ色空間以外の色空間には、その定義域範囲内では表現できない色が存在します。
（実用観点では無意味ですが、負値や定義域外の値を許容すれば全ての色を表現できるとも言えます。）
※ この回答は、XYZ色空間定義で用いる均質な単色を想定しています。金属光沢や構造色(structural color)といった複雑な物理特性をもつ広義の "色" はまた別の議論となります。

『定義の上では CIE XYZ色空間 を用いると「標準的な観察者(人間)が知覚できる全ての色情報」を値として表現できます。これ以外の全てのカラースペースは、数式としてはXYZ色空間との間で相互可逆変換を行えます』大変参考になりました

RGB 系は光で色を表現するディスプレイ（ CRT / 液晶 / EL ）向け色表記
CMYK 系はインクで色を表現する印刷物向け色表記
である、という理解があるなら Q1 も Q2 も結局は同じ質問というか
コンピュータで使う「浮動小数点数」はほぼすべての機械で IEEE754 であり、つまり２進数有限桁で表記します。無限桁が必要な循環小数も有限桁でぶち切っているから演算を繰り返せば必ず誤差が蓄積します。
そもそも原理的にインク自体が発光するわけではないので、インクでは表現できない、表現しにくい色ってものは必ずあります（金属光沢とかはインクで表現するのが極めて困難です）あとはコストの問題で、使うインクの特性によって色域が違うとか普通にあります（高価なインクを使うと表現可能な色が増える）本来 RGB→CMYK 変換ってのはそういうのを加味して行うものです。なので印刷所や使う紙やインクが全部決まった後に一度だけ行うような代物です。イラスト作成中に何度も色空間を変換するとか普通はしません。 Wikipedia の 色空間 なども参照のこと。

追加質問に対して
なんだか禅問答のような気がしてきました。これは絶対に XY 問題っス。
「可逆変換できる色もありますか？」に対する答えは、そのような色が１色でもあれば Yes 。オイラたち読者側は本当にそういう質問がしたいのかって思ってしまうわけです。
あと @yohjp さんも言っていますが XYZ 色空間と RGB 色空間は可逆変換できるようにシステムを作ったのだから、やはり Yes 。ただし XYZ と CMYK は多対１の変換になるわけだから１対１の相互変換はできないです。
色空間の変更と
色の変更とは
全く違うものなのですがその辺誤解してないですか？
色空間を変える≒媒体を変えるってことっスよ？
色空間を変えるってことは、イラストを、最初は水彩画で描き始めたけど、途中でフレスコ画に変換する＝描きなおす、その後またさらに西陣織にて服にする、ってことに近いです。 RGB→CMYK 変換は、ディスプレイ上で鑑賞するのに最適なように sRGB 空間を使った絵を、印刷物で鑑賞するのに最適なように CMYK 空間に変換する、ために行います。こう考えると、色空間を変換しまくるなんてことは普通にはあり得ないって思いません？

「多対１の変換になるわけだから１対１の相互変換はできない」。全く異なるわけではないけれども、各空間ごとに取り扱える範囲が違うのだと理解しました。「色空間を変換しまくるなんてことは普通にはあり得ないって思いません？」そんなことをして何になるんだ、と言われれば確かにその通りなのですが、色空間の変換式が、掲載ページ毎に微妙に異なっていることが気になったので質問しました。

1年前まで印刷屋で働いていた経験から、以下の意見を述べさせていただきます。
※印刷用にデジタルデータを変換することに関しての意見です。
▼可逆変換の難しさ
・完全な変換は不可能です。
・人間の色覚判断能力程度の変換は可能ですが、完全な変換はできません。
・基本的に1回以上の変換は避けるべきです。
いくつかのカラースペースが提案されていますが、より抽象的に説明すると理解しやすいでしょう。
▼例
・10段階のグレースケールで描かれた画像を「A」とします。
・256段階のグレースケールで描かれた画像を「B」とします。
「A」の画像での色の表現「0」は、
「B」の画像では256 / 10≒25のカラーパターンに分けられます。
つまり、「B」の「10」「15」「20」といった色の段階はデジタル情報として正確に保持されず、「A:0」として扱われます。
そのため、カラースペースを変換する際は原則として1回のみと考えるのが適切です。
▼1回以上の変換を避けるべき現実的な理由
例えば、Adobe IllustratorでCMYKに準拠した印刷用のデータを作成するとします。このデータは正しくCMYKで表現されています。
しかし、このデータを表示するモニターは通常RGBであり、色の分解能は256段階です。
そのため、モニター上でCMYKデータを見る時点で既に1回の不可逆な情報欠落が発生しています。
その後、このデータを印刷し、印刷物をスキャナーでデジタル化すると、再び異なる色に見える可能性があります。
印刷業界では、正確な発色を確保するためにインクの濃度や混合比率を調整します。
これには専用のカラースキャナーが使われますが、スキャナ機材の性能は現物とデータの整合性をどの程度比較できるかによって決まります。
また、カメラで撮影された画像も有限の解像度で表現されますが、実際の物質がすべて256段階の色で表現されるわけではありません。
このように、完全互換を目的とした設計の規格ではないカラースペース等の規格は、原則完全な変換は困難であると考えられます。
まして印刷用とデジタル描画用のカラースペースは完全互換しません。
もし完全互換可能になるとすれば色・材質表面情報（材料種別や硬度、面形状）・表示空間情報（湿度や気圧、重力等）など様々な要因をデジタル化しつつ、尚且つより膨大な解像度を与えなければならないと思います。

「モニター上でCMYKデータを見る時点で既に1回の不可逆な情報欠落が発生しています」。変換する時点で情報は欠落してしまうのですね。モニター上で再現できないだけで内部では元の色情報データを存在させることはできないかな、と疑問に思い質問しました。

説明に誤解が生じておりました。仰るようにシステム側はデータを保持しております。システム側で保持している限りはCMYK準拠データなので印刷機へリクエスト処理を行っても問題ありません。システム側でRGBに変換したのち、印刷リクエストを行うなどするとCMYK＞RGB>CMYKと再変換が発生するため、これによってデータ欠損が累積していくという趣旨です。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Q1: 異なるカラースペース間での色数値変換
異なるカラースペース間での色数値変換は、基本的に近似変換です。各カラースペースは異なる色域（カバーする色の範囲）を持っているため、一つのカラースペースから別のカラースペースへ変換する際には、完全な一致を得ることは難しいことがあります。特に、RGBとCMYKのように全く異なる物理的基盤（光の加算的混合とインクの減算的混合）に基づくカラースペース間では、変換は特に複雑です。
また、変換のプロセスで使用されるアルゴリズムによっては、細かな色の差異が失われることがあります。変換を繰り返すと、これらの小さな誤差が蓄積され、最終的に顕著な色のずれが生じる可能性があります。
Q2: 共通の色数値とカラースペースの限界
異なるカラースペース間で完全に可逆的な色数値を持つことは、基本的に不可能です。これは、各カラースペースが持つ色域の違いに起因します。たとえば、あるRGB値で表現できる鮮やかな青は、CMYKで完全に再現することができないかもしれません。その逆もまた真です。
さらに、光の照射条件やインクの品質、紙の種類などの物理的条件によって、同じ色数値でも異なる見え方をすることがあります。このため、異なる物理的条件下で同一の色を再現することは困難であり、カラーマネジメントシステムを用いてこれを補正する必要があります。
一般的に、カラースペース間で色を正確に変換するためには、色管理プロファイル（ICCプロファイルなど）を使用して、異なるデバイスやカラースペース間での色の再現性を向上させることが重要です。これにより、色の一貫性を保つことができますが、全ての色が完全に再現可能であるわけではありません。

「異なるカラースペース間で完全に可逆的な色数値を持つことは、基本的に不可能です。これは、各カラースペースが持つ色域の違いに起因します」参考になりました

発光と反射は異なる物理現象なのでそれぞれに異なった理屈で数値化したものに共通点がなくても仕方ないと思います。両者をむりやり変換し続けることに意味があるとも思えません。
